# What's the difference between these two php-fpm configuration files?

Tags: php

I see `php-fpm.conf` and `php-fpm.d/www.conf` --they are both config files for php-fpm.

(And just to be clear: neither one of those files is the same as the main `php.ini` config file, which is something I'm familiar with and a totally separate and different thing.)

So: why does php-fpm have/need two separate config files?

Comment: It doesn't. But you can use as many as you want. It often makes sense to split the configuration into multiple files. For example that allows to bundle module specific configuration directives to be bundled with the actual module which makes installing module packages easy, robust and revertable.

Comment: How would you compare a fpm config against a php config?

Comment: I’m not sure I know what you’re saying, but I think that might be the answer I’m after… If you wouldn’t mind elaborating I would appreciate it. (Neither of these is the main PHP.ini file, by the way, if that’s what you mean.)

Comment: You mention the fpm config, then the php.ini. Those are two different configuration files for two different binaries. I’m just puzzled by your question.

Comment: I mention 3 different files in my original post. The 3rd one I mention is `php.ini` which I understand is the main PHP config file. The first two I mention are both for php-fpm. "Why does php-fpm need two separate config files" is exactly my question. Is that more clear? (I don't know how I can be more clear...)

Answer (score 0):

FPM uses php.ini syntax for its configuration file - php-fpm.conf, and pool configuration files - php-fpm.d/*.conf  (php-fpm.d/www.conf in our case).

You can put all pool config files in php-fpm.conf file but sometimes it's much more convenient to put them in separate files - www.conf, cli.conf, etc.